# Cannot set mongoDB host to MongoRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have the following **User** structure:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String role;
    private String username;
}
```

And a mongo **repository** interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{
}
```

I put the following config in **XML** file:

```
<mongo:mongo host="www.example.com" port="12345"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="geospatial"/>
</bean>
```

Now I try to **save** the user:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public void foo() {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername("Humberd");
    newUser.setRole("USER");
    userRepository.insert(newUser);
}
```

Despite setting host as *"www.example.com"* spring still connects to my localhost:

```
org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:42}] to localhost:27017
```

What am I doing wrong? How to set the host to the custom one?

Comment: did you find any solution to this. I'm facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is what I finally did:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.tryton.repositories"})
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    private String host = "myhost";
    private int port = 12345;
    private String databaseName = "fooDB";

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new Mongo(host, port);
    }

}
```